# How to import multiple files and save to multiple data files?

Tags: r

instead of,

```
split1<- read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/intern/splitstx/splitstx (1).csv")
split2<- read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/intern/splitstx/splitstx (2).csv")
.
.
.
split36<- read.csv("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/intern/splitstx/splitstx (36).csv")
```

I did not want to save in 1 files since when all combine, it consist of 5GB csv data and my ram didnt support it. So is there any other solution?

Comment: maybe the `ff` package can be of help

Comment: how to do it?sorry im a newbie in r

Comment: I have no experience with the [`ff` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html), but it has datastructures that are stored on disk instead of RAM. If the amount of RAM is your limitation and you want all the data, this is probably your only option.

Comment: Also: stop adding the `RStudio` tag, this is not a specific `RStudio` question.

Comment: ok thanks.i will try that package

Comment: cant use that package.my r is not version 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

All you want to do is merge the data in the CSV files?  Try something like this.

```
library(data.table)
setwd("C:/Users/xxx/Merge Multiple CSV Files/CSV Files/")

WD="C:/Users/xxx/Merge Multiple CSV Files/CSV Files/"
data<-data.table(read.csv(text="CashFlow,Cusip,Period"))

csv.list<- list.files(WD)
k=1

for (i in csv.list){
  temp.data<-read.csv(i)
  data<-data.table(rbind(data,temp.data))

  if (k %% 100 == 0)
    print(k/length(csv.list))

  k<-k+1
}
```